# MS Dynamics AX 2012 field control embeded

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

In Dynamics AX 2012, I found a field control can be embeded in another field control, I don't understand what that means, and how they did it, see picture below.     Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no picture attached to you post, but from your description I would guess that you are 
either referring to the **Segmented Entry Control** or to the **Reference Group control**.

The **Reference Group Control** is used toghether with surrogate keys for foreign key replacement in forms. This is described here:

[Whitepaper: An introduction to surrogate key replacement in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35369)

In general the segmented entry control represents the finacial dimensions.
Each segment (field) in the control represents a single financial dimension.
The combination of all segments(financial dimension) is stored in the **DimensionAttributeValueCombination** table and the there is a single field (RecId) in the transaction table which refers back to the **DimensionAttributeValueCombination** table.

Here is more information on SEG:

- [Financial Dimensions: Segmented Entry Control](http://junctionsolutions.com/blogjuice/4-segmented-entry-control/)
- [MSDN: Segmented Entry (AX 2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300646.aspx)
- [MSDN: How to Add a Segmented Entry Control to a Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300644.aspx)